# Customize Windows Run Dialog

Tags: windows-98, run-dialog

Is it possible to customize the Windows Run dialog (invoked with Win+R)? For example, is it possible to replace the default `Type the name of a program...` message with something more interesting?

In particular, I'm interested in doing this on Windows 98 (after seeing [this image](http://windows95tips.tumblr.com/post/34337868903)).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why Windows 98?! :|

Comment: @Aceth: I stumbled upon [this](http://windows95tips.tumblr.com/post/34337868903) and thought it'd be cool to implement in real life.

Comment: You can try running a [strings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439.aspx) utility to see if you can locate which EXE or DLL contains that particular message. Then once you have backups in place, a hex editor or Resource Hacker or similar can be used to modify the file and see if it works, or causes Windows to explode.

Comment: @Karan, Thanks! This actually found something on Windows 7 in the `winsxs` folder. However, I'm not sure changing these files would work: I have the 64-bit version of Win7, and the `System32` and `SysWOW64` folders both contain versions of `Shell32.dll` without the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I figured it out for Windows 98, and it should also work on Windows XP. Here's the info for future generations.

The dialog box is stored in `C:\Windows\System\Shell32.dll`, and it is possible to edit it using [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/). After opening the DLL in the program, go to `Dialog\1003\1033`, and the rest should be pretty straightforward.

- All of the captions, strings, etc. are in the main window.
- To remove the context help button from the title bar, remove `DS_CONTEXTHELP` from the `STYLE` line at the top.
- To add an icon to the DLL, select `Action-->Add a new Resource`, then choose it from your computer and give it a unique resource name (a number).
- To replace the default icon already present in the dialog, right-click it, choose `Edit control`, then change the `Caption` to the resource name of the new icon.

***Important:*** The OK button won't work if you just delete everything else and let it be. To fix this, set its ID property to anything other than 1.

***Important 2:*** Windows won't let you replace the original `Shell32.dll` while it's running. Reboot into MS-DOS and copy from there.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to do this on Windows 7, as the `Shell32.dll` there doesn't contain the dialog box. If anyone has an idea, please share.

[image: result]